# Unable to upload Offline Events to facebook business manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I hope you can help me with this issue.

I am trying to upload an offline event to my business manager but I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "error_subcode": 2044005,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Terms of Service Not Accepted",
    "error_user_msg": "You can't use offline event sets until the terms of service are accepted for ****. Please accept the terms of service at https://business.facebook.com/offline_events/?business_id=***********&show_tos=1 and try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "*****"
  }
}
```

When I try navigating to the link in order to accept the terms, it leads me to a broken link. I already validate that I have an offline event set by doing a get on it.

How can I navigate to the page to accept the terms and services in order to post to my offline conversion set?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. lim: do you have any solution?

Comment: @yigal No I have not found anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can only accept manually at once through Web UI, use the link below.
https://www.facebook.com/ads/leadgen/tos